# silverlight: creating a file in memory and offer it for saving it locally

Tags: silverlight, filesystems

I need to create a file in memory (without saving any copy of it in a filesystem) and then offer it to the user so that he/she can save it in his filesystem. How can I do this in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight, access to files can be only user initiated.
This means, saving the file using a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog%28VS.95%29.aspx) class.
Follow the link, there is an example there.